# Cannot connect to mongodb replica set on google cloud vm instance

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I deployed a mongodb-replica set on google cloud vm (marketplace solution) and I can connect to it via browser-ssh where I created a database and enabled accessControl. However, I cannot connect to the set from the outside world or from an app on app engine.

my connection string looks like this:

```
mongo "mongodb://[user]:[pass]@35.207.100.1:27017,35.207.100.2:27017/mydb?replicaSet=rs0&authSource=admin"
```

And this is what I get:

```
2020-03-08T17:27:42.204+0100 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 35.207.100.1:27017
2020-03-08T17:27:42.204+0100 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to 35.207.100.2:27017
2020-03-08T17:27:47.209+0100 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set rs0
2020-03-08T17:27:47.209+0100 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set rs0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
```

What I already did:

- Gave each instance a static external IP-Adress (it responds to pings)
- Create a firewall rule for incoming (and also outgoing) traffic on `tcp:27017` from `0.0.0.0/0` (tried limiting via network tag and also tried to enable it for all instances - no differences in outcome), see the following images:

  - [image: firewall overview for mongo]
  - [image: firewall rule incoming traffic]
  - [image: network interface details of the primary]
- I also disabled the firewall (by allowing all traffic from all sources on all ports to all instances) for testing purposes and the error messages appeared way faster than before and it tries to connect for like 20 times - before only 3 times. So there seems to be an impact.
- my `/etc/mongod.conf` has the following entries:

  ```
  net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  replication:
    replSetName: rs0
  ```

and this config is the one that is used by the process as `ps aux` shows me:

```
mongodb   5862  0.4  1.1 1468472 91388 ?   SLsl Mar07   5:10  /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Also, all the machines are in the default network

netstat on the primary of the set shows me:

```
Proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0    0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22544/mongod
```

Also, when I browser-ssh to one of the instances I can connect to the set only via internal IP's but not via external IP's.

I assume there's still something wrong with the network configuration, but I cannot find out what it is.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you still have an issue? If yes, try to change **`Priority`** to make it **lower** that you already have for other rules.

Comment: I got it solved (see my solution below). When adding the new rule I set priority to the default value of 1000 (by just not changing it) but maybe that's the missing piece that actually solved it. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's what solved my problem (even though I don't understand why).

- Delete my firewall-rule and re-add it with the same configuration and the same network-tag (I just did copy & paste)

  **EDIT:** What might have made the difference was the `priority` of the rule as [stated in this comment by Serhii Rohoza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590693/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-replica-set-on-google-cloud-vm-instance?noredirect=1#comment107215218_60590693). Before it had the lowest priority of 65534 after re-adding the default value of 1000.
- adjust my connection-string to:

  ```
  mongo "mongodb://[user]:[pass]@35.207.100.1:27017,35.207.100.2:27017/dbname"
  ```

Just doing one of these things didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the analysis displayed in the bottom, the port is not open for the rest of the Ips.

[image]

Make sure the Firewall rules are enabling this. To do

- configure the firewall rule in Google cloud console
- provide a tag in your firewall rule
- tag your instance with the same tag as the firewall rule

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I did, as you can see on the 2nd screenshot. I used the tag mongodb-servers in the rule and on the vm's. As you can see on the screenshot, the rule applies to this vm's since they're listed under "applicable to instances"